# glm starting values not accepted log-link

Tags: r, offset, glm

I want to run a Gaussian GLM with a log link and an offset.
The following problems arise:

```
y <- c(1,1,0,0)
t <- c(5,3,2,4)
```

No problem:

```
exp(coef(glm(y~1 +  offset(log(t)), family=poisson)))
```

with `family=gaussian`, starting values need to be specified, it works here:

```
exp(coef(glm(y~1, family=gaussian(link=log), start=0)))
```

but does not work here:

```
exp(coef(glm(y~1 +  offset(log(t)), family=gaussian(link=log), start=0)))
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : cannot find valid starting values: please specify some"

Does anyone see what's wrong (hopefully just in my coding) ?

Comment: "does not work" is less useful than the actual error message, which is "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : cannot find valid starting values: please specify some"   I played w/ some simple `glm(y~1+offset(junk))` and all worked fine. I think you have a very small data set and some rather unlikely offsets, so glm simply can't find a fit.

Comment: My "very small data set" is what people call minimal example let you

Comment: Is it not because you are trying to take to log of 0?

Comment: No, starting value should be on linear predictor scale, that means it starts with beta_zero=0. Other starting values same error. Wonder why R asks for starting values when they are actually specified...

Comment: @Andi I was meaning taking the log of 0 in the `y` values. Try it with non-zero positive `y` and it will work, and with no `start` required.

Answer (score 16):

Here are the results of some archaeology that explains what's going on, deep within the `glm` function:

Debugging (with `debug("glm")`) and stepping through the function shows that it fails at the following call:

```
if (length(offset) && attr(mt, "intercept") > 0L) {
  fit$null.deviance <- eval(call(if (is.function(method)) "method" else method, 
    x = X[, "(Intercept)", drop = FALSE], y = Y, weights = weights, 
    offset = offset, family = family, control = control, 
    intercept = TRUE))$deviance
}
```

This is an attempt to calculate the null deviance for the model. It's only evaluated if there's an intercept term and an offset term (I'm not sure why; it may be that the default null deviance calculated by the previous call to `glm` is wrong in that case and must be recalculated?). It calls `glm.fit` (the default value of `method`), but *without* starting values because these are usually unnecessary for the intercept-only model.

Now debugging inside `glm.fit` to see what happens: we get (within a call to the family function, `gaussian()`) to:

```
  if (is.null(etastart) && is.null(start) && is.null(mustart) && 
    ((family$link == "inverse" && any(y == 0)) || (family$link == 
        "log" && any(y <= 0))))
    stop("cannot find valid starting values: please specify some")
```

and we see that because the starting values were not passed through, because a log link is used, and because some `y` values are equal to zero, the fit fails.  So this is a case that should happen if (and only if?) an offset and an intercept are both specified, a log link is used, and there are zero values in the response.

If you `dump("glm",file="glmtemp.R")`; add the line

```
    start = start[1], etastart = etastart[1], mustart = mustart[1],
```

to the call that fits the null deviance (i.e. the one shown above); and `source("glmtemp.R")`, it seems to work OK ... I *think* this should be a reasonable general solution.  If anyone wants to bring this issue up on the R development list, feel free.

Comment: With your addition to the call the technical problem is solved. Thank you! Can you also give me a hint why the estimated parameter does differ from the poisson-glm ? (same offset, same log-link) Without an offset term both estimates are identical.

Comment: I don't have time to dig through this, but why would you expect them to be the same?  I think it's a special case that the non-offset models are identical ... I would just work through the definition of the model step by step (i.e. find the minimum expected variance-weighted sum of squares on the link scale, with or without the offset)

Comment: Nice digging! :) I think there is a better fix though: just add `mustart = fit$fitted.values`. I've submitted a patch at https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16877 .

Answer (score 10):

I looks like `start` isn't being recognised when `offset` is present. You are trying to take the log of 0 in the `y` values which is `-Inf`. `glm` obviously cannot deal with this when looking for a solution without being given some help by `start`. A small perturbation in your `y` values will permit a solution.

```
exp(coef(glm(I(y+.Machine$double.eps)~1 + offset(log(t)), family=gaussian(link=log))))
(Intercept) 
  0.1481481
```